# Stylesheet not properly loading, or linking

Tags: c#, html, css, visual-studio, stylesheet

I can't get my style sheet to work in Visual Studio. I have tried quite a few things. Here is my code as it currently is.

Index File (Home Page)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <title>Index</title>
    <link href="indexStyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <h2>red</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS (The file type is .css)

```
h2 { color: red;}
```

Screen shot of file hierarchy

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As your css file is in the same directory as your index.html, you don't need to specify a path starting from the root of your project.

This should do it.

```
    <link href="indexStyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Edit:

Also, I didn't catch that immediately, what is most likely the cause of all your problems is that your h2 isn't inside the body tag !

Comment: I made the changes recommended, but unfortunately I'm still not having any luck. I edited the post to reflect your suggestions. Thanks for your help, and thanks in advanced for any future help.

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache, maybe? There is no apparent reason as to why the CSS can't be loaded.

Maybe the issue here is your config.

Comment: I cleared the browser cache, and tried different browsers. no dice. I'm quite confused as to what could be causing this.